# Having trouble understanding a portion of code in gadgetfs

Tags: c++, c, usb

In the example file "usb.c" located at:

http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/usb.c

Inside the `init_device` function, I am having trouble understanding why the author wanted to convert the buffer to a pointer. Here is a shortened code snippet:

```
char buf [4096], *cp = &buf [0];
int fd;
int status = 0;
char *DEVNAME = "musb-hdrc";

if (status < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "?? don't recognize /dev/gadget %s device\n", "iso");
    return status;
}

fd = open (DEVNAME, O_RDWR);
if (fd < 0) {
    perror (DEVNAME);
    return -errno;
}

*(__u32 *)cp = 0;   /* tag for this format */
cp += 4;

/* write configs */
cp = build_config (cp, hs_eps);

/* and device descriptor at the end */
memcpy (cp, &device_desc, sizeof device_desc);
cp += sizeof device_desc;

status = write (fd, &buf [0], cp - &buf [0]);
```

Wwhy did the author want to create `*cp`? wouldn't writing to the address of the first element of an array just write to the array? It seems like when he actually goes to use what he wrote to `*cp` he just ends up using the buffer anyway...

Also, what exactly is he doing with:

`*(__u32 *)cp = 0;`

Is that some sort of pointer to a pointer thing? Why add 4 to it and then just write over it afterwards?

I feel like I understand most of whats happening in this procedure but a couple things have left me perplexed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author creates `cp` so that they have a pointer into the array. They can then move that pointer around with `cp += 4;` (we'll see why steps of 4 in a second) and do stuff at this new location.

`*(__u32 *)cp = 0;` first casts the pointer to the type `__u32*`, which I can only assume is a pointer to an 4 byte unsigned integer. They then dereference this pointer and write the value 0 to the object it points at. Remember that the buffer is made up of `char`s, which are 1 byte in size, and the pointer `cp` is a `char*`. They're casting the pointer to a `__u32*` so that they can write to the buffer 4 bytes at a time. So when `cp` is pointing at the first element in the buffer, they end up setting the first 4 bytes of the buffer to 0. That's why they move the pointer along 4 elements, so that they can deal with everything after the first 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

It means "cast `cp` to `__u32 *`, then derefernce it (outer `*`) and assign `0`.
It is done so that a correct number of bytes (4 bytes, assuming `__u32` is a 32-bit type) is written.